# How to load html text in CDHtmlDialog?

Tags: mfc

In MFC can we load html text in CDHtmlDialog?

In CDHtmlDialog whether we can load only html file or can we load html text also.

In CDHtmlDialog  I need to load html text. The html text is dynamic so I dont want to use file?

Can we load html text directly in CDHtmlDialog?

Comment: You can load an HTML and call a java script function in the HTML (with arguments) using GetDHtmlDocument. Refer https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/813078/Calling-Javascript-function-from-CDHtmlDialog-in-M

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to read from a file or HTML resource.

To make changes dynamically, create `IStream` on html source string, and use the `IPersistStreamInit` interface to change the source dynamically. `CHtmlEditView` already does this through [`SetDocumentHTML`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54542c1c.aspx#chtmleditctrlbase__setdocumenthtml) method.

For `CDHtmlDialog`, use a default HTML source, load it using a file or HTML resource:

```
<html>
<body id="findme">
    blank
</body>
</html>
```

And call `SetElementHtml(L"findme", L"Make changes to content...");`, however this method cannot change the entire html source. See also [`SetElementHtml`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bed8k60.aspx#cdhtmldialog__setelementhtml)

Comment: Thanks Barmak. In HTML file I have text fields in many columns  in the table.

How to dynamically  set value only  to any particular text field of html and how to validate the text field and assign the value to c++ variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the html page using

```
CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> pDoc2;
HRESULT hr = GetDHtmlDocument(&pDoc2);
if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
{
    CComQIPtr<IHTMLDocument3> pDoc3 = pDoc2;
    CComBSTR docStr;
    CComPtr<IHTMLElement> pElem;
    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = pElem->get_innerHTML(&docStr);
        pElem->put_innerHTML(htmlbuffer);
    }

}
```